# Cannot access data from Nav View in the embedded collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am having trouble passing data from my Nav View to its embedded collection view and onward.  I have attached what I am trying to do below.

**I realize this is probably not the best approach for this, and advice is appreciated**

I wanted to know:

- How to access data from a Nav View in the embedded collection view within it.
- If a less horrible way exists that implements this.

[image: Storyboard Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of data isn't meant to be trapped in the navigation structure like that. You need a big-picture sense of MVC to get at an efficient solution.

The essence is to *decouple* your views from each other, and attach connectors to a model according to MVC.

You might implement a singleton pattern if the whole App truly shares one model:

```
class MyCentralDataModel {
    static let globalModel = MyCentralModel()
    var floatingPointValue = 0.0
}
```

And attach a listener to the slider that updates the central model whenever the slider changes. Then, any view that needs access to this model consults the central model when the view loads.

Comment: Just wanted to follow up, albeit two years later, I did exactly that and it works perfectly.  Thank you.